# Data item current values not updated: internal-work queues get next item: blueprism

Tags: queue, dataitem, blueprism

I am following a tutorial for blueprism (beginner). In the tutorial, I am asked to create a process, add an action stage and use the internal business object called work queues, with the action get next item. In the outputs tab of this get next item action, I used the auto-generate buttons in the Store In column to create the output data items.
After saving and running the process, these data items are supposed to be populated and have current values. However, my data items don't hold any current values. Can someone explain why?
Also, after publishing the process and refreshing the control room, I am not able to see the queue items in my queue management tab. I have attached here the pictures of the following:
[Process-Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj2i7.png) | [Get Item Action properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGu3H.png) | [Queue Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiUQr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please check if there are any pending items in queue?

If there are no pending items, then using action "Get next item" returns blank values.

Comment: Yes, actually I realized that I needed to add to the queue first before being able to use the get next item action. It was just not clear in the tutorial, so for anyone who comes across the same issue while following the blue prism foundation training, you should do the next part of the tutorial first.